# Установка DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf

Использую в приложении окно из набора `mahapps.metro`. Возникла проблема задания контекста.
Если делаю так, то все работает нормально:

```
public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainVM(); ;
    }
}
```

Если задаю контекст прямо в разметке, то тоже все работает:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow.DataContext>
    <vm:MainVM/>
</Controls:MetroWindow.DataContext>
```

Но если задавать контекст таким образом в `App.xaml.cs`, то контекст не устанавливается:

```
    MainVM mainVM = new MainVM();

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        new MainWindow() { DataContext = mainVM }.Show();
    }
```

Подскажите, что делаю не так?

---

**UPD.**
Проблема была в файле App.xaml.

В строке `x:Class="WpfApplication.App` было указано другое пространство имен, поэтому файл App.xaml.cs лежал просто мертвым грузом и в нем ничего не выполнялось.

Comment: Я не силён в WPF и не уверен, что это связано с вашей проблемой, но у вас происходит задание DataContext сначала в конструкторе, а потом в инициализаторе. Т.е., вот это: `DataContext = new MainVM();` (из конструктора `public MainWindow`) замещается вот этим: `{ DataContext = mainVM }`. Это **разные** экземпляры `MainVM`

Comment: мое предположение, что view уже где-то вызывается, а строка new MainWindow() { DataContext = mainVM }.Show(); не выполняется. Проверьте его, закомментировав эту строку. Если ничего не изменится, то вы найдете причину

Comment: А в app.xaml убрали `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"` ?

Comment: @IvanParfentev, Пробовал убирать. Окно просто не появляется.

Comment: Очень странно, должно работать. Дайте минимальный воспроизводящий пример.

Comment: И как вам правильно подсказывают, уберите `StartupUri` из `App.xaml`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Должно работать, видимо не вызывается код:

```
 new MainWindow() { DataContext = mainVM }.Show();
```

и до этой строчки у вас дело не доходит. Добавьте строчку в конструктор класса App.xaml.cs

Comment: или base.OnStartup(e);  в конце метода

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/127547)

Comment: @BlackWitcher Поправил

Comment: @user2455111, Не работает вариант ни с конструктором, ни с `OnStartup(e)` в конце метода. С обычным окном код из вопроса отрабатывает как положено, но если меняю окно на `Controls:MetroWindow`, то контекст не задается

Comment: @maxwell подключил MetroWindow, по скрину можно увидеть call stack, что следующим шагом будет конструктор ViewModel. https://s17.postimg.org/8rnyxt4j3/image.png. Т.е. отрабатывает все на ура. Предлагаю написать маленький пример и выложить его, чтобы у нас была возможность найти ошибку